# Paypal Controller Overriding/Extending not working

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal-express, core

I have Magento 1.9 CE and I'm trying to create a new module for extend the class `Mage_Paypal_Controller_Express_Abstract`, but it doesn't work.
Here's the code:

`Name_Module.xml`  in /app/etc/modules

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config>
    <modules>
     <Name_Module>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <depends></depends>
     </Name_Module>
  </modules>
</config>
```

`config.xml` from /app/code/local/Name/Module/etc/

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
  <modules>
    <Name_Module>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Name_Module>
</modules>
<frontend>  
    <routers>
          <paypal>
            <args>
                <modules>
                        <Name_Module before="Mage_Paypal">Name_Module _Paypal</Name_Module >
                </modules>
             </args>
        </paypal>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

and `Abstract.php` app/code/local/Name//Controller/Paypal/Express/

```
<?php
include_once('Mage/Paypal/Controller/Express/Abstract.php');
class Name_Module_Paypal_Express_Abstract extends        Mage_Paypal_Controller_Express_Abstract{

/**
 * Submit the order
 */
 public function placeOrderAction()
 {
      //code
  }
 }
```

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: "it doesn't work". What doesn't work? What should it do and doesn't do? Please describe any faults, errors (add error logs), screenshots, etc...

Comment: use  `<depends>Mage_Paypal</depends>`  instead of   `<depends></depends>`

Answer (score 1):

You can't overwrite an Abstract class in Magento. The class that you are trying to overwrite `Mage_Paypal_Controller_Express_Abstract` is an abstract class and hence can't rewrite by *controller-rewrite* way.

If you want to edit `placeOrderAction()`, the only possible way is put that core file in `local` codepool. For this :

1. Create a file `app\code\local\Mage\Paypal\Controller\Express\Abstract.php`
2. Copy paste original content of the file `Abstarct.php` to this file.
3. Now edit `placeOrderAction()` according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

In Magenton abstract class does not override ....SO you can not rewrite class

```
Mage_Paypal_Controller_Express_Abstract....
```

Also there lot issue in code;

use `<depends>Mage_Paypal</depends>` instead of `<depends></depends>`

Comment: unfortunately nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

`Mage_Paypal_Controller_Express_Abstract` is a basic class which implements common methods, you dont need to rewrite it.

Instead you need to define which payment method you want to modify excalty. In your case I suppose it is a `Mage_Paypal_ExpressController`.

So, all you need to rewrite `Mage_Paypal_ExpressController` class and implement own logic for method `placeOrderAction()`.

It will work because `Mage_Paypal_ExpressController` extends `Mage_Paypal_Controller_Express_Abstract` and all methods you define in `Mage_Paypal_ExpressController` will replace methods from parent class.